# DIV changing shape unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a circle in a canvas to match the dimensions of a div. I can't understand what's wrong here (aside from the bad style), as the result is an ellipsis, which looks like  the canvas size has been stretched after the drawing ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zwa64/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

scrH = $(window).height();
scrW = $(window).width();

// place map
$('body').append("<div id='pagUserStart_map1' style='border:5px solid red;'></div>");
var map = $("#pagUserStart_map1");
map.css("width", scrW - 60 + "px");
map.css("height", map.css("width"));
map.css("top", scrH / 2 - map.height()/2);
map.css("left", (scrW - map.width()) / 2);

map.css("position", "absolute");
map.css("margin", "0 auto");
map.css("border-radius", "50%");
map.css("z-index", "100");

//place canvas
$('body').append("<canvas id='canvas1'></canvas>");
var canvas = $("#canvas1");
canvas.width(map.width());
canvas.height(canvas.width());
canvas.css("position", "absolute");
canvas.position({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: map
});

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");  

// draw circle in canvas
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height /2 ;
var radius = 50;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
context.shadowBlur = 10;
context.shadowColor = '#656565';
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#B8CADE';
context.stroke();
});
```

I understand that something goes wrong between when I use JQuery to reference 'canvas1' and when I use getElementById. But why? It seems like the code is not executed sequentially. I've lost a few hours googling around and playing with the code... I really need your help.

Comment: You are using width and height of body so it will use 100% width and height. use some predefined width and height.
try updated fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zwa64/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to make a difference... looks the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Canvas size correctly:

```
canvas.attr('width', map.width());
canvas.attr('height', map.height());
```

And you will recieve this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UsGQ.png

Comment: Great! Is this **exactly** the same as `canvas.width=map.width(); canvas.height=map.height();`?

Comment: "Great! Is this exactly the same as canvas.width=map.width(); canvas.height=map.height();?"
- Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Set the canvas element width instead of the canvas css width:

```
// draw circle in canvas
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");  
canvas.width=map.width();
canvas.height=map.height();
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height /2 ;
var radius = 50;
```

Comment: It works. But what is the difference between this and setting the CSS attribute? I looked everywhere and can't find an answer.

Comment: Actually it works for the size but a new problem arose: now the `position` method doesn't seem to be working anymore. Here is the new fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9d7w2/)

Answer (score -1):

Simple change your `absolute` position to `fixed`.
Like this
$(document).ready(function() {

```
scrH = $(window).height();
scrW = $(window).width();

// place map
$('body').append("<div id='pagUserStart_map1' style='border:5px solid red;'></div>");
var map = $("#pagUserStart_map1");
map.css("width", scrW - 60 + "px");
map.css("height", map.css("width"));
map.css("top", scrH / 2 - map.height()/2);
map.css("left", (scrW - map.width()) / 2);

map.css("position", "fixed");
map.css("margin", "0 auto");
map.css("border-radius", "50%");
map.css("z-index", "100");

//place canvas
$('body').append("<canvas id='canvas1'></canvas>");
var canvas = $("#canvas1");
canvas.width(map.width());
canvas.height(canvas.width());
canvas.css("position", "fixed");
canvas.position({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: map
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will not solve the main issue. For canvas elements you need to set its *bitmap* size with the writable width and height attributes/properties. CSS only affects the *element* size.